# How can I create a file object through byte array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I got this array from file[0] -> blob.slice -> filereader.asArrayBuffer ->  Uint8Array

> array = [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 51, 13, 10, 37, 226, 227, 207, 211, 13, 10, 13, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111, ...]

How could I do the reverse engineer? Create a new File Object from the above array?

I'm creating a file object through

> bytes =  [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 51, 13, 10, 37, 226, 227, 207, 211, 13, 10, 13, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 13, 10, 60, 60, 13, 10, 47, 84, 121, 112, 101, 32, 47, 67, 97, 116, 97, 108, 111, 103, 13, 10, 47, 79, 117, 116, 108, 105, 110, 101, 115, 32, 50, 32, 48, 32, 82, 13, 10, 47, 80, 97, 103, 101, 115, 32, 51, 32, 48, 32, 82, 13, 10, 62, 62, 13, 10, 101, 110, 100, 111, 98, 106, 13, 10, 13, 10, 50, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106]
>
> let testFile  = new File([bytes],"application/pdf")
>
> let testFile  = new File(bytes,"application/pdf")

Is my code making sense? If not, how do I convert those bytes into a correct one?

## Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

```
content = Uint8Array.from([37, ... 106])

file = new File([content])

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

reader.onload = function (e) {
    const fileType = doTask(e.target.result);
    
}

function doTask(arrBuffer) {
    const byteArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        byteArray.push(arrayBuffer[i]);
    }
    let headerContent = '';

    // Create the headerContent
    for (let i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        headerContent += byteArray[i].toString(16);
    }
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

}
```

Comment: @JonasWilms Actually thats exactly what [`new File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) needs, as long as the inner `bytes` is a *typed array*.

Comment: @bergi oh, I had an *instinct* ... seems I was completely wrong ..

Comment: @newBike you're probably looking for `bytes = Uint8Array.from([ … ]); return new File([bytes], …)`

Comment: @Bergi Let's me try your way!

Comment: I'm afraid you're solution is wrong. Please see my update. I could not do it reverse way which means the conversion is not correct.

Comment: Wonder if it should be file = new File(content)?

Comment: @TedFitzpatrick don't work~

Answer (score 2):

I believe I resolved this. In my situation, I have a Google App Script project I'm working on and the DriveApp Blob class has a .getBytes() function.

What you need to do is take that Byte[] and convert it to an unsigned 8 bit array and pass that to the File constructor. Be sure to also include the second required argument of filename as well.

One example from App Script

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var bytes = file.getBlob().getBytes();
new File([new Uint8Array(bytes)], 'filename', {type: 'mimeType'})
```

So for anyone else, simply get your byte array data in a variable called bytes. Type is optional, but useful.

```
new File([new Uint8Array(bytes)], 'filename', {type: 'mimeType'})
```